# How Do I Read MySQL Username using Php Script?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Hello I have been having troubles for hours researching this and various trys and fails and cant seem to use a PHP script to read usernames for MySQL
This is what I am using to

```
 $sql1="UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='1' WHERE username = '".$username."'";
 $sql2="UPDATE `as_users` SET reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE username = '".$username."'";
 $sql3="UPDATE `as_users` SET end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)     WHERE username = '".$username."'";
 $result1=mysql_query($sql1,$link);
 $result2=mysql_query($sql2,$link);
 $result3=mysql_query($sql3,$link);
```

This is how i'm getting username and it works when I put it in echo for HTML but wont when I use it for query.

```
include 'templates/header.php';
$userDetails = $user->getDetails();
$user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users`");
$username =$userInfo['username'];
```

Heres whats in my header.php it's system im using for login but thats not the problem the 
way im querying to my datebase is.

```
 <?php
include 'ASEngine/AS.php';
if(!$login->isLoggedIn())
header("Location: login.php");
$user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
 $userInfo = $user->getInfo();
?>
```

thanks everyone I debug it and fixed and, sorry my code is sloppy i'm not the best with PHP and SQL queries I appreciate all your help, how would I go about quering all the sql1-3 into one query how would that look? and also how would I convert this into PDO for no SQL injections.

```
$link = mysql_connect('IP Here', 'Database here', 'Password here') or die ("Err;data   connection");
mysql_select_db('Database here',$link) or die ("Err: db selector");
```

Hello thanks to everyone for helping me with my current issue if so could you check if this code has any vulnerabilities as-well?

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO  `paypal_mysqltable_name` (datenow,    item_name,   item_number,       payment_status,    payment_amount,   payment_currency,  payer_email,     payment_type,   custom, 
invoice, first_name, last_name, address_name, address_country, address_country_code, address_zip, address_state, address_city, address_street) 
            VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'item_name','$item_number','$payment_status', '$payment_amount','$payment_currency','$payer_email', '$payment_type','$custom' ,'$invoice','$first_name','$last_name','$address_name','$address_country','$address_country_code','$address_zip','$address_state','$address_city','$address_street')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$user` and where does `$userInfo` come from? Your code is highly confusing.

Comment: It comes from the stuff I included from header.php

Comment: But we don't know that code in header.php?! Please share it with us.

Comment: Added code above for header.php

Comment: I really hope this isn't live; its vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: It isn't live at the moment can you help me fix my problem in anyway maybe injection aswell?

Comment: Try debugging your code. What does $sql1 and so on return? false? what does mysql_error() say?

Comment: Look up php's PDO.  `mysql_*` functions are deprecated for a reason.

Comment: I cant debug it because its in an IPN system, how would you go about debugging an IPN system?

Comment: Instead of using mysql you should use mysqli or PDO as Daedalus said. Then use mysqli_real_escape_string or PDO::quote to protect your script against SQL injections. Also parse the input data, because it could contain malicious content.
I don't know what a IPN system is, but in this case it's really important to debug in my opinion.

Comment: Read Above for response.

Comment: And you could combine your queries to one, so you would need only one request to your database server instead of three. That's much faster ;)

Comment: @Pixelmonster While it's good to use MySQLi or PDO, the reason is NOT `real_escape_string` or `quote`; it's [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)/[`bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Comment: Though you should check the content of the user's input.

Comment: Posted it as answer because of the code highlighting.

Comment: Of course your new code has vulnerabilities, whenever you put variables directly into the query string(at least most of the time), you're asking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP-Style mysqli (you can also use PDO)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='1', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Pixelmonster, Thank you so much it works perfectly thanks for making this non injectable if you could I would appreciate it so much if you could also see if the code I posted above has any of these vulnerabilities. Again thank you so much.

Comment: Please read this for more information about SQL Injections. http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php